# how to exclude one url from Basic Auth

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Using Apache/2.4.41. Trying to exclude 1 URL from Basic Auth.  The URL I want to exclude is `/index.php?r=admin/remotecontrol` I've tried many different ways to specify this, but none have worked for me. This is my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    # if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    # otherwise forward it to index.php
    RewriteRule . index.php
</IfModule>

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Content"
AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/.htpasswd
Require expr %{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#.*/remotecontrol#
Require valid-user
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: What Apache version? Depending on whether <2.4 or not, there’s a basic difference between whether you would have to use `Satisfy`, or a `<RequireAny>` container to specify multiple conditions that would allow access. And to get the condition for the special URL implemented to begin with, I’d set an environment variable, either using `SetEnvIf` with the Request_URI as input, or via a RewriteCond/RewriteRule combination that matches that URL, and uses the `E` flag.

Comment: Version is in my initial message: 2.4.41

Comment: Oh, sorry, overlooked that. Have you tried wrapping both those `Require` into a `<RequireAny>` container then? (Assuming the way you try to match the target URL there works on its own?)